# Docker - all-spark-notebook - Mounting local drive

Tags: macos, docker, pyspark, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

Working with docker and jupyter notebook.

https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/all-spark-notebook/

I have sucessfully launched the notebook, but I am having real trouble mounting a local directory to run some tests.

```
   docker run -d -p 8888:8888 jupyter/all-spark-notebook 
                -v users/username/documents/work:/home/jovyan/work
```

Seems to load, but then I get

```
  Session terminated, terminating shell...[C 13:45:24.497 NotebookApp]          
   received signal 15,
```

I am using Mac OSX mountainlion.

I am not sure where Docker see's my root directory and how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of mounting a local folder using a relative path, try with the full absolute path:

```
-v /users/username/documents/work:/home/jovyan/work
```

Answer (score 0):

A different way of mounting the folder of the container(/home/jovyan/work) to the folder of your local machine(/path/to/your/local/folder). When jupyter has been started on your browser, open the ***work*** folder and you will find the files from your local machine have been mounted into the container.

```
sudo docker run -it --name jupyter-spark -p 8888:8888 --mount src="/path/to/your/local/folder",target="/home/jovyan/work",type=bind jupyter/all-spark-notebook
```